# angularjs expressions with double curly braces do not work in tag attributes

Tags: angularjs

Attempting to use an expression in an attribute like:

```
<span ng-show="{{ ($state.current.name !== 'main') }}">
    <button class="btn btn-small"><a ui-sref="main">Take me home!</a></button>
</span>
```

... results in the button displaying on every page in spite of the fact that the following displays false when on the main page:

```
{{ ($state.current.name !== 'main') }}
```

Comment: just figured it out --- no curly braces

Answer (score 4):

Since `ng-show` is an angular attibute (directive), you don't need to interpolate `{{ }}` inside them.

```
<span ng-show="$state.current.name !== 'main'">
```

All *Angular aware* attributes (so, anything beginning with `ng` etc) do not need to be interpolated because angular already knows they are an expression.

Comment: What about ng-src, ng-disabled, ng-href and the lot. They all need curly braces and are as you say "angular aware attributes beginning with ng". There seems to be some inconsistency on the angularjs team when designing the app.